# How apply an order to CONSTRUCT in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

Doing this query SPARQL

```
select ?s ?p ?o 
WHERE
{

  GRAPH <graph_url> {
    ?s ?p ?o
  }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?s) DESC(lang(?o) = "it") DESC(lang(?o) = "en") ?o
```

I order each element in the graph_url, such that given two element rdf of the same type I have first the element with attribute value "it" and then the elements with attribute values "en".

However if I apply a CONSTRUCT over it

```
CONSTRUCT  { ?s ?p ?o }
WHERE
{

  GRAPH <graph_url> {
    ?s ?p ?o
  }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?s) DESC(lang(?o) = "it") DESC(lang(?o) = "en") ?o
```

I loose this order. I found out that CONSTRUCT doesn't mantain the order given by ORDER BY.

There is a way to construct an rdf with construct such that the graph resulted is ordered?

Comment: there is no such guarantee, in the best case your triple store resp. SPARQL engine does respect such an `ORDER BY` clause - the reason why it isn't part of the standard is that the result of a `CONSTRUCT` query is an RDF graph which in fact is a **set** of triples.

Comment: If your result is `N-Triples` you could simply sort it in a post processing step, e.g. when using Linux use `sort` or something

Comment: Indeed, you could also stick to a `SELECT` query with `ORDER BY`, ask for `TSV` as resultset format and append a dot for each line in the result as a post-process.